# Excel COUNTIF Function Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel

I have a dataset where I have to find the number of times the letters `"age"` appear while excluding the actual word `"age"`.

If I use the `countif` function, I get all words that contain `"age"`, but not sure how to exclude the actual word `"age"` from that count. I have tried to limit the word length, for example only count words that are greater than 3 characters and contain `"age"`, but have been unsuccessful.

I appreciate all of the suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data inhabits column `A`, you could use the `COUNTIFS` function in the following way:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*age*",A:A,"<>age")
```

#### EDIT:

Following clarification that cells contain multiple words, please try the following:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*age*",A:A,"<>age",A:A,"<>* age",A:A,"<>age *",A:A,"<>* age *")
```

Comment: That gave me the same answer as =COUNTIF(A:A, "*age*"), so unfortunately that doesn't work. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Yes, with conditional formatting I am able highlight cells that contain age and from there manually count how many cells do not include the actual word. I know that I have 55 cells that include "age," and 6 of which include the actual word... therefore, I should have 49 cells as my final. Unfortunately both formulas are giving me 55.

Comment: I have multiple words in each cell, not sure if this is causing the problem.

Comment: @EmilySechrist In that case - please try the formula in my edited post above.

Comment: @LeeMac Technically this still might not work. You are assuming that "`age`" is separated by a space, but this isn't necessarily the case. (The OP will have to clarify.) For example if a cell contains: "`age: 10`", your `COUNTIFS` formula would return `1` but should return `0` (by the OP's current requirements).

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 I take your point and appreciate the complexity of your solution and your evident knowledge of Excel, however, I think there is a balance between code being maintainable & readable, versus accounting for every conceivable circumstance - this of course depends on the OP's data.

Comment: @LeeMac I agree with you on all points. I still upvoted your answer. Only reason I brought it up is because the OP had mentioned that your formula wasn't working, and I thought perhaps it could be due to `age` being standalone separated by something other than a space. As I stated in my answer, my formula is pretty exhaustive, but complex. I agree simpler solutions such as your `COUNTIFS` solution exist, if the OP can exclude certain circumstances. All depends on how the OP responds here.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more exhaustive, and requires a helper column, but could be what you're looking for:

I have this array formula in cell `B1`, searching for instances of `age` in cell `A1`, excluding the stand-alone word `age`.

```
= SUMPRODUCT((MMULT((ABS(ABS(IFERROR(CODE(MID(A1,MODE.MULT(IF((MID(A1,
  ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-2)),3)="age"),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):
  INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-2))*{1,1}))+{-1,3},1)),32)-93.5)-16)<13)+0,{1;1})>0)+0)
```

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the formula.

And then you can just use a simple `SUM` at the bottom of the column to sum up all of the instances.

The formula essentially finds each instance of `age` in the string, looks at the character immediately before and after it, and if either of these characters are a letter (capital or lowercase), then a match is found. The formula counts the matches.

See below for working example. I came up with several examples to demonstrate how it works.

[image]